# Design a function to_tree that converts a linked list into a binary search tree, bt_node* to_tree(list_node* n)

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I have some basic code but don't know i'm going in the right direction for this scenario.

-Design a new function to_tree that converts a linked list into a binary search tree.

-The function signature must be bt_node* to_tree(list_node* n)

-On exit, the returned binary tree must contain all items that the input list contains.

```
// linked list node
struct list_node{
  jlist_node* next;
  int value;
};

// binary tree node
struct bt_node {
  int value;
  bt_node* left;
  bt_node* right;
};

bt_node* to_tree(list_node* n){
  bt_node* temp = new bt_node  //new node
  temp = (temp->n);
  if (temp != Null){
    if((n->next)<(n->value)){
     (temp->left) = (n->next);
    }else{
      (temp->right) = (n->next);
    }
    to_tree(list_node* (n->next);
  }
}
```

There may be a few errors but I'm just trying to get the basic understanding since it part of a lower level assignment. Can respond in pseudocode.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a bit vague, and the example isn't [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it does look like you're on the right track. I recommend describing your approach in more detail beyond posting the code. Are there any special characteristics of the input list (e.g. sorted)? How are you determining the root node and maintaining balance in your tree? What is the expected output? These are important questions, because you can technically make a BST by sorting the list and making the largest element the root, but this isn't in the spirit of the question.

Comment: Pleas add programming-language tag

Comment: "some errors" It is approximately 100.00% wrong.You should try starting with a function `insert_into_tree`. The function needs to accept two arguments, a tree and a number, and return a modified (bigger) tree. Continue from there.

Comment: @n.m adding a insert_into_tree would essentially be adding a "helper" function right? I realized that this code would essentially make a "winding" road not a tree. How could I recursively use a helper function to "build" a tree?

Comment: Adding an item is core tree functionality. Comverting a list to a tree is a small utility function.

Comment: @n.m. ah! nice hint. I will look into my insert functions setup.